# SLAM on Jade ROS

Tags: ros, 3d-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Folks,

I want to know  you about SLAM project on Jade ROS, I see videos on youtube, but none of them explain how this is done. Could any one help in listing projects for beginners like me rather than turtle in the ROS wiki.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241163/slam-on-jade-ros/) by [marwa eldiwiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27638/marwa-eldiwiny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many SLAM algorthims wit tutorials. A quick search finds [quite a few](https://www.google.com/search?q=ros+slam+tutorial)

There's a relatively cohesive set of examples at: http://learn.turtlebot.com/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0